# IIS Authorization Rule Issue for AD Group

Tags: iis, authorization, rule

I want to configure the IIS to accept only the request from users who belong to a particular AD Group. This configuration is required at Default Website level. So on Default Website I enabled Windows Authentication, went to Authorization rules option,choose Add Allow Rule and put the AD group in "Specified roles or user groups:".

This does not work with any AD group (for which I am a member). This work well when I put the AD user in the next option "Sepcified User" https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbqhK.png .

Can some one please help on what I am missing. As stated above I want to do it at Default Website level on IIS so there is no Web.config invovled.

Cheers.

Comment: I figured out, actually I should not be adding the AD group in Authorization rule option in IIS. First I need to create a new Group in Locals User Group in Computer Management and add the AD group there. Then put this new local group name in IIS Authorization rule.

Answer (score 0):

Real old thread, but in case anyone Googling this issues comes across the same problem:

I could only get this to work with AD groups that are have their Group Type set to "Global" in AD. Ones set to "Security" wouldn't work for me.

In IIS this is specified under the "Roles" section on the IIS Authorization rules.

I have only Windows Authentication selected as an authentication method. Strange IIS bug?

Here is the web.config for reference

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="DOMAIN\TestGroup" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```